# SQL ORACLE - CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not know why the code is complaining when I am comparing  = 'N2' what type of comparator operator I can use. Can somebody help me? ORACLE

```
select
CASE T1.process_code
  when (select T3.OPTIONAL_CODE as Tax_Code
        from GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY T3
        where T3.voucher_no = ('2018001625')
    and ACCOUNTING_YEAR = 2018 
    and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '5'
    and ACCOUNT like '3%') = 'N2' 
  THEN (select T4.OPTIONAL_CODE as Tax_Code
        from GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY T4
        where T4.voucher_no = ('2018001625')
    and ACCOUNTING_YEAR = 2018 
    and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '5' 
    and ACCOUNT like '3%')
  ELSE 'HEllo'
  END process_code
from  lora1app.GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY T1,
```

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your query with some sample data and needed result. [MCVE] can be useful to improve your question

Comment: Is `GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY.OPTIONAL_CODE` of numeric type ?

Comment: My guess is that more than one row is being returned by the subquery? It would help if you posted the error message.

Comment: *'I do not know why the code is complaining'* Neither do we. But you could help us by **posting the actual error message**.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because the `case` should probably be:

```
(case when (select T3.OPTIONAL_CODE as Tax_Code
            from GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY T3
            where T3.voucher_no = ('2018001625') and
                  ACCOUNTING_YEAR = 2018 
                  ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '5'
                  ACCOUNT like '3%'
           ) = 'N2' 
      then . . .
```

Or perhaps:

```
(case when T1.process_code =
           (select T3.OPTIONAL_CODE as Tax_Code
            from GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY T3
            where T3.voucher_no = ('2018001625') and
                  ACCOUNTING_YEAR = 2018 
                  ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '5'
                  ACCOUNT like '3%'
           ) 
      then 'N2'
```

But the searched case and simple case forms cannot be mixed.